# Getting Started with WiFi on Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn how to work with WiFi (e.g. connecting to networks automatically, starting new connections, etc) on Android.

Can anyone suggest any good sites or books that have helped them in the past?

Comment: What do you mean by "wifi" programming? Can you please add some more details?

Comment: I also need this resources... hey give me a PM if you've done it so far. :D

Answer (score 36, accepted):

okay ...

Blogs :

- https://web.archive.org/web/20210228070142/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/turn-off-turn-on-wifi-in-android-using.html

Corresponding WiFi doc:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html

Books :

- [Professional Android 2 Application Development](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527.html) has a chapter for Bluetooth, N/W and Wifi

Comment: good article @Reno, But what about sending broadcast message through that wifi?